# View and Edit SP list from another site with Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: list, list-view, list-definition

I have been searching for a way to view my SP list into another site. I want the members to be able to delete items so the list changes on my site. I tried to create a view of the list and created a datasource in SPD with the view. But the datasource only showed non-editable items, and not even all the items were shown.
I also tried to save the list into a file and upload it into the member site but only got an exception: "Value does not fall within the expected range".

Is there any better ways to solve my problem? The sites are in the same sitecollection.

I'm also using an list-definition if that might help.

Best Regards,
Blenni

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't simply providing them with links to the actual list?

Comment: The List resides at a AdminSite that is unavailable for the users. I want the users to view this list at another site, filtered to just display List items where a specific column=current user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest either the [Content Query Web Part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981241%28v=office.14%29.aspx) or the [Data View Web Part](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2009/display-sharepoint-list-site-data-view-web-part/) as each has their strengths.  However, the sticking point will be the deletion mechanism.  You  might need to display the items [via popup](http://blogbaris.blogspot.com/2012/09/open-sharepoint-2010-display-edit-new.html) and let the users delete them from there.

Comment: I acctually solved this problem myself by saving the list view into a gallery instead of file. The view was displayed but as you said it's a problem now. The members are also supposed to add items to my site but in the same way they are only able to delete in another site which shows the list.